# PhoneGap/Cordova: Status Bar won't change to Light on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have an issue with PhoneGap/Cordova. StatusBar is not changing to light although I have the StatusBar plugin installed.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.vibrate(3000);
    StatusBar.styleLightContent();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might have to hide the statusbar first and show it again before a new style can be shown. Have you already defined other preference in your config.xml file like [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#configxml)? If it changes style, remove this preference again. In this case you might have to hide it first and show it again. Hope this helps.

Comment: LightContent only set the text to white, not sure if that what you expect to happen